# Get-PrintConfiguration output to file and screen

Tags: powershell

I tried to export the screen result to a file. On the screen, the output is 5 columns with truncated info:

```
$Printers = Get-Printer *
Foreach ($Printer in $Printers){Get-PrintConfiguration -PrinterName $Printer.name}
```

[Screen Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUGA8.png)

I tried to make the column size wide enough by using format-table -autosize, the output become 1 table per printer:

```
$Printers = Get-Printer *
Foreach ($Printer in $Printers){Get-PrintConfiguration -PrinterName $Printer.name | Format-Table -Autosize}
```

[one table per printer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDJls.png)

But if I export it to csv, it becomes a huge file and many lines are not make sense to me:

```
$filename = 'PrintConfiguration'
$Printers = Get-Printer *
Foreach ($Printer in $Printers){Get-PrintConfiguration -PrinterName $Printer.name | Export-Csv d:\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))_${env:COMPUTERNAME}_$filename.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation}
```

[366kB CSV file for a 5 printer system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPycS.png)

What I did wrong and how can I fix that?

Comment: Try moving your `Export` outside your `foreach` loop. Also, what does, "*it becomes a huge file and many lines are not make sense to me*" mean?

Comment: For this 5 printer system, the CSV is 366kB size. Please see the sample screen on my original post.

Comment: Then only export the fields you need, using Select-Object, before you export

Comment: `Get-Printer | Get-PrintConfiguration | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty PrintCapabilitiesXML | Export-Csv d:\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))_${env:COMPUTERNAME}_$filename.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: @Daniel,

Thanks and I found I need to add the **asterisk** for the Select-Object with -ExcludeProperty as follow:  
  
  
`Foreach ($Printer in $Printers){Get-PrintConfiguration -PrinterName $Printer.name | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty PrintCapabilitiesXML | Export-Csv d:\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))_${env:COMPUTERNAME}_$filename.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation}`

Comment: You don't need the Foreach ($printer in $printers) part  at all.  Did you try just copying and pasting my comment?  It will work just by piping out from Get-Printer right to Get-PrinterConfiguration and then to Select-Object, etc.